# Ruby Regex and string variable

Tags: ruby, regex, watir

I am trying to match a string with a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) given a variable that contains the string with a regular space.  The string I am looking for is the text in a HTML link/anchor and I am using Watir (note the non-breaking space).

```
<a onlick='DoSomthing()' href=''>Some&nbsp;Text</a>
```

There appears to be a difference between a regex created by // and by Regex.new.

Interactive Ruby says the following is true (where my_text = 'Some Text'):

```
/Some Text/ == Regexp.new(my_text)
```

Yet while this returns True:

```
browser.link(:text, /Some Text/).exists?
```

This does not:

```
browser.link(:text, Regexp.new(my_text)).exists?
```

Nor does this:

```
browser.link(:text, /#{my_text}/).exists?
```

I've also tried the following with no luck:

```
Regexp.new(my_text.gsub(' ', '[[:space:]]'))
```

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this match?

Comment: If you create a page that just has that one link, do the above attempts work? They worked for me when I tried them (while using watir-webdriver with Firefox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use alternation:

```
browser.link(:text, / |&nbsp;/).exists?
```

Also, try upgrading Ruby and gems. I've heard weird regex issues in Watir resolving magically that way.

Comment: I've just discovered that the issue apparently has nothing to do with Regex.  The problem is somehow rooted in passing a string constant to a method.  I am going to post that issue separately.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: As best I can tell this was a glitch in the IDE (RubyMotion).  The exact same code I was using before is now producing different results.  While Regex/Watir are matching fine with just a regular space (now) I am marking this as the answer as swapping spaces for '( |&nbsp;)' seems more robust.

Answer (score 1):

A non breaking space is an html entity, and regex afaik does not recognize that as a space, so you need to convert one or the other before matching.

```
my_text = 'Some&nbsp;Text'
```

in other words, I don't think regex would ever match a space to "&nbsp;". change your search string, or the source text, whichever is easier...

Comment: I had seen elsewhere that [[:space:]] would work.  I don't know if it should/shouldn't.  The crazy thing is that /Some Text/ works just fine but as soon as I stick "Some Text" in a variable it refuses to work.